# OnClick event on compound UserControls

Tags: winforms, user-controls

I want to create a `UserControl` with several controls inside. These controls should behave simmilar to the radio buttons, i. e., the status of one of them affects the status of the rest. To do that I would like to be able to handle the `OnClick` event on each of the controls from the parent.

One solution could be to call a method of the parent, to perform the global `UserControl` change, from the child controls' `OnClick` method. Something like:

```
class Child : UserControl
{
    ...

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs z_args)
    {
       // do own stuff

       ((PartentType)Parent).ChangeStatus(this);
    }

    ...
}
```

This is a solution, but I wonder if there is a more standard an elegant way to solve this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is very bad, a control should never depend on having a specific parent.  Do it the same way any Windows Forms control does it: if something interesting happens that a parent might be interested in then raise an event:

```
    public event EventHandler StatusChanged;

    public int Status {
        get { ... }
    }

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs z_args) {
        // do own stuff
        //...
        var handler = StatusChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

Consider putting the event raising code in a private setter for the Status property.